# Click on the navigation dots and it doesnt set the class active

Tags: jquery

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sbzcuoff/1)

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(evt){
    var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    console.log('target =>' + target);
    if(target.length){
      evt.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate(
      {scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);
      $('a[href^="#"]').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });


  $(window).scroll(function() {
      var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (windscroll >= 20) {
          $('.section').each(function(i) {
              if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 5) {
                  $('.scrolling-navigation li a.active').removeClass('active');
                  $('.scrolling-navigation li a').eq(i).addClass('active');
                  console.log('top ' + $(this).position().top);
              }
          });

      } else {
          $('.scrolling-navigation li a.active').removeClass('active');
          $('.scrolling-navigation li a:first').addClass('active');
      }

  }).scroll();
```

There are two click and scroll to display dots with active class which paints dot black.

Scroll up and down, the dots are set to active correctly and accordingly. But when tried to click on dot, it doesn't set active correctly. Only it will be set to active if click on same dot twice. Also, first dot is set to active correctly.

Why is it not set to active when click on second dot once?

Comment: Have you consider using [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the scroll is not reaching your second sections position because the scroll has reached the bottom of the page, you can check for that first. Also take notice what @Stoyan Dekov said.

I have updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbzcuoff/7/):

```
var offset = 20;

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(evt){
    var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    if(target.length){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate(
            {scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= offset) {
        $('.scrolling-navigation').fadeIn();
        if(windscroll + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
            $('.scrolling-navigation li a.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.scrolling-navigation li a').eq(1).addClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('.section').each(function(i) {
                console.log('top ' + $(this).position().top);
                if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll) {
                    $('.scrolling-navigation li a.active').removeClass('active');
                    $('.scrolling-navigation li a').eq(i).addClass('active');
                }
            });
        }

    } else {
        $('.scrolling-navigation').fadeOut();
        $('.scrolling-navigation li a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.scrolling-navigation li a:first').addClass('active');
    }

}).scroll();
```

The problem why the dot was not set to active was that after the click event (where the active class is set correctly) the scroll event set back the first dot to active because the page has reached the bottom an it wont pass yor if test. If you add the check to see if it reached the bottom of the page it works properly.

**One final but VERY IMPORTANT update**:

Right now you are setting the active class in the click event AND the scroll event. That makes the "jumpy" behaviour, just leave the scroll event to change the active class and now it works perfect.

Comment: You can add some `<br>` at the bottom of your page to see it working without reaching to the bottom of the page.

Comment: thanks alot for the explanation and I tried to fiddle with code but when click on last 5th section, it will not show active :(. hmm.

Comment: Which 5th section? The Fiddle ypu provided contains only 2 sections?

Comment: Yes for fiddle 2 sections, but I added more than 2 sections for more testing. Clicking on each dot scroll to correct section, but the dot is not set to active except that previous dot is still set to active. It is weird.

Comment: You should update your question then, because now it is different to your original one.

Comment: Ok will update fiddle shortly within an hr. thanks :)

Comment: Good to know. Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Second dot is not set correct because of your check.

```
if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 5) {...
```

Lets say your second view starts at 300px. The scroll will set to exactly 300 while your check will return you are still in the first part (295 < 300).

Remove the `-5` and it will set the second value active as soon as the scrolling reaches its target.

I've also commented out the set on click as it is a bit confusing.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sbzcuoff/3/).

Comment: this is not working for me, it never changes the active at all. I think the problem is with $(this).position().top, not the -5

Comment: The problem is that the scroll reaches the bottom of the page and the offset to top wil never be enough. If you add a lot of `<br>` at the end it will work (but it is not the solution to the problem)

Comment: His code will only work in a case where each `page`'s height is more than (>=) the screen height. [like this](http://deepmind.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its calling that twice, once for each of the buttons.

```
   $('.section').each(function(i) {
          if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 5) {
              console.log('top ' + $(this).position().top);
          }
      });

    <li><a href="#1" class="tooltip-left active" data-tooltip="Test 1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" class="tooltip-left" data-tooltip="Test 2"></a></li>
```

I just made those changes and it seemed to work.